# Python requests:- simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I am trying to get some order details using the python `requests` library. The API is working fine with the postman, but when I try to run it with python the following error occurs.

```
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

[image: URL and Params]

[image: Access Token]

I am using the following python code to call the API in the screenshots:

```
import requests
url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/purchases"
header = {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization":'token {}'.format('eyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')}
data = {"from_date":"2021-06-15T07:19:32", "to_date":"2021-09-16 00:01:09"}
response = requests.get(url, params=data, headers=header)
print(response.json())
```

The result I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Have you ever looked at the output of `print(response.text)` and looked that it is also in the correct json format

Comment: Yes, I have tried printing the response text and it comes like an HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I need to add a text `"Bearer "` in front of the token passed in the Autorization parameter of header section as the following because the token is to be passed as a Bearer Token:

```
header = {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization":'Bearer eyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}
```